# No visual after loading geotiff in Qgis Dufour

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I installed the latest version of QGis 2.0 for mapmaking. Before I used the 1.8 version and I had no problems in loading Geotiffs. With the latest version, it loads the same files but it doesn't show any image. I haven't got any clue why in this version it doesn't load/show these files. Does anybody know?

Comment: Have you activated On-the-fly-reprojection? If yes, try without it.

Comment: Too bad, i turned it off but issue remains